# How can I load properties in spring boot from a custom source?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application. I do not want to store sensitive properties (e.g. DB password) in my application yaml or system environment variables. How can I load properties from a custom source before the startup of the context?
Meaning of custom property source: I want to write the code which reads these properties, because they are not stored in files or on classpath.

Update:
I want to store my properties in AWS SSM Parameter Store.

Comment: Interesting question, may I ask where from you'd like to retrieve these properties then?

Comment: I encrypt my passwords from @PropertySource or application.properties. A better way is to use LDAP to store your values on startup for larger applications that is the best way to go.

Comment: Consider using Spring- Cloud- Config. You can store your properties encrypted and have them decrypted on the client side, or have them decrypted on the server and then sent over to the client. You can store your property files on the local file-system, git/svn repository, vault etc.

Comment: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/

Comment: I want to store my properties in AWS SSM Parameter Store.